# Suppress white area of two overlapping solutions in ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the following expression:

$$dx = x\left(-0.5+0.59y+1.3(x+y)-(x+y)^2-0.2z\right)=0$$

I tried this using the following code:

```
    dx:=x*(-0.5+0.59*y+1.3*(x+y)-(x+y)^2-0.2*z)
    c = ContourPlot3D[dx==0,{x,0,1.5},{y,0,2},{z,0,2.3},PlotRange->All]
```

I get the following output:
[image]

The area in which the parabolic surface intersects the trivial surface is white. Why does this happen? How can I suppress this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the option MaxRecursion you can refine the plot:

```
dx := x*(-0.5 + 0.59*y + 1.3*(x + y) - (x + y)^2 - 0.2*z)
c = ContourPlot3D[dx == 0, {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2.3},PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Alternatively, increase the `PlotPoints` or use a combination of `MaxRecursion` and `PlotPoints`